# Trying to migrate Rally Defect Requirement to JIRA

Tags: ruby, jira, rally

Using the Rally/JIRA connection I am trying to synchronise them.

https://help.rallydev.com/jira-5-installation-user-guide

I am trying to map the Requirement (UserStory) field for Defects to a custom field in JIRA.

Here are my field mappings

```
    <FieldMapping>
  <Field><Rally>Name</Rally>         <Other>Summary</Other></Field>
  <Field><Rally>Description</Rally>  <Other>Description</Other></Field>
  <Field><Rally>FormattedID</Rally>  <Other>RallyKey</Other></Field>
  <Field><Rally>Status</Rally>        <Other>Status</Other></Field>
  <Field><Rally>Priority</Rally>        <Other>Priority</Other></Field>
  <Field><Rally>Requirement</Rally>  <Other>RallyUserStory</Other></Field>
</FieldMapping>
```

I am using the RallyReferenceFieldHandler to map this to a custom field

```
<RallyReferenceFieldHandler>
    <FieldName>Requirement</FieldName>
    <ReferencedFieldLookupID>FormattedID</ReferencedFieldLookupID>
</RallyReferenceFieldHandler>
```

I am getting this error message:

**RallyEIF::WRK::JiraRestConnection.block in validate - Field Handler field_name Requirement not found**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

would you mind posting more of your config with all of your field mappings and field handlers?

My only guess at the moment is that your  is inside your  block.  If it were in the wrong place, you might get an error like you are seeing.  It should be inside a  block - for example:

```
<Connector>
    <FieldMapping>
        <Field><Rally>FormattedID</Rally><Other>OtherFormattedID</Other></Field>
        <Field><Rally>Requirement</Rally><Other>RallyUserStory</Other></Field>
    </FieldMapping>

    <RallyFieldHandlers>
        <RallyReferenceFieldHandler>
            <FieldName>Requirement</FieldName>
            <ReferencedFieldLookupID>FormattedID</ReferencedFieldLookupID>
        </RallyReferenceFieldHandler>
    <RallyFieldHandlers>

    <OtherFieldHandlers>
    <!-- Other Field Handlers here -->
    </OtherFieldHandlers>
</Connector>
```

Comment: I seemed to have put my RallyFieldHandlers section in the wrong place. This worked for me. Thanks!